# Is there any way to get a USDZ file without a Mac?

Tags: xcode, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit, usdz

The issue I'm having is that the only way I know of (currently) generating a `USDZ` file is through the Xcode Command Line Tools. This means I'm obligated to use a Mac server if I want to define this as a service.

Is there any other way which would enable me to scale this and get rid of the Mac server?

I have read about the `USD` format and browsed the issues in their repo, and they say that they're currently developing tools for converting from `USD` to `USDZ`, but they don't have an ETA yet.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The answer is YES.**

As we all know Apple and Pixar together developed a `USDZ` file format. It's a compact and simple format that's designed to let people share AR content "while retaining great 3D graphics and even animations." The `USDZ` format is addressing the typically large storage size of AR content, which can make it harder to share information easily and quickly. Companies like Adobe are adopting the `USDZ` format to work with its Creative Cloud platform, which includes apps like Photoshop and Dimension. ***Thus, `USDZ` file format is not platform-dependant***.

A `USDZ` package is merely a zero compression, unencrypted `Zip Archive`. `USDZ` packages are maximally useful within production pipelines. A `USDZ` file is read-only - editing its contents requires first unpacking the package and editing its constituent parts using appropriate tools because `USDZ` is a "core" `USD` file format.

> Of course, you can generate a `USDZ` file without a Mac. For this you need a plugin for any of the following professional tools: ***Autodesk Maya, The Foundry Katana, or SideFX Houdini***. For more detailed information read [this Pixar's webpage](https://graphics.pixar.com/usd/docs/USD-3rd-Party-Plugins.html).

[image]

Comment: And now Apple released USDPython tools too!

Comment: Pixar, to be precise! Apple supported it.

Comment: The majority (99%) of professional tools (like Maya, Houdini, Nuke, VRay, Fusion or RenderMan) support Python scripting out of the box.

Comment: Yeah, the majority of them are paid apps though. I was looking for something free (like a Blender plugin) or to build a USDZ from scratch (building the USD myself too). I knew about the Maya USD plugin but I wasn't able to use it because of that.

Comment: Autodesk Maya has a Non-Commercial version. Pixar RenderMan too. You can use Maya NC licence for 3 years.

Comment: Free Student Version of Maya 2018:
https://www.autodesk.com/education/free-software/maya

Answer (score 0):

Nvidia provides [USD Pre-built Libraries and Tool](https://developer.nvidia.com/usd)s for Windows and Linux based on the USD source from Pixar along with many other amazing assets for USD.